# Output problem in mysql query in MFC program

Tags: c++, mysql, mfc

I'm currently working on a small MFC program that outputs data from a mysql database.
I can get output when i'm using an sql statement that does not contain any variable eg.

```
select album from Artists;
```

but when i try to use a variable the program compiles but i get no output eg.
    mysql_perform_query(conn,select album from Artists where artists = '"+m_search_edit"'")

Here is the function for mysql_perform_query:

```
MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *conn, const char* query)
{
   // send the query to the database
   if (mysql_query(conn, query))
   {
     // printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
     // exit(1);
   }

   return mysql_use_result(conn);
}
```

And here is the code block for outputting the data:

```
struct connection_details mysqlD;


mysqlD.server = "www.freesqldatabase.com";  // where the mysql database is
mysqlD.user = "**********";  // the root user of mysql 
mysqlD.password = "***********"; // the password of the root user in mysql
mysqlD.database = "***************"; // the databse to pick

// connect to the mysql database
conn = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);


CStringA query;
query.Format("select album from Artists where artist = '%s'", CT2CA(m_search_edit));
res = mysql_perform_query(conn, query);



//res = mysql_perform_query (conn, "select distinct artist from Artists");



while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL){
CString str;
UpdateData();

str = ("%s\n", row[0]);

UpdateData(FALSE);
m_list_control.AddString(str);

 }
```

The m_search_edit variable is the variable for an edit box.
I am using Visual Studio 2008 with one copy of this program unicode and one nonunicode,
I also have a version built with VC++ 6.
Any tips on how I can get output from the databse using the m_search_edit variable??

Comment: Not directly, but your query is wide-open for SQL-injection

Comment: Yeah, its only  small college program though, so SQL injection is my bottom priority at the minute.

Comment: Is the `m_search_edit` variable the `CEdit` object, or a `CString`?  How are you getting the string from the edit control?  `CEdit::GetWindowText`?  `DDX_Text`?

Comment: I also note you've commented out the check for an error in `mysql_perform_query`, and you're using the returned `MYSQL_RES*` without checking it for `NULL`.  Is it possible the query just failed?  What have you tried to verify that all the parameters are correct?

Comment: m_search_edit is a CString, i`ve also tried it as a CEdit.

I just realised i dont have any code in to get the string from the edit box. I`m assuming that is whats gone wrong, time to lookup GetWindowText.
That must seem like an awful stupid mistake to make, but in my defence I havent really done much MFC programming before and this is the biggest program i`ve ever attempted to make.

Comment: That would explain the lack of output :-p

Comment: For future reference, that's important information when asking a question like this too -- make sure we see the whole path from CEdit all the way to the query and that you tell us the types of all the variables that you refer to.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help. I finally got it wokring using this code:
    void CLISTSQLDlg::OnEnChangeEdit1()
    {
 CDialog::OnInitDialog()
 

     UpdateData();
     CString strStoreValue;
     strStoreValue = m_search_edit ;
     UpdateData(FALSE);



    }